# Unable to update babel-preset-es2015 to babel-preset-env

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs

I cannot successfully update babel from preset-es2015. I get a warning whenever I try to install a package via NPM:

> npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:  Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!

However, when I follow the advice given at babeljs.io/ev and run the command

> npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

I get multiple 'gyp ERR!' and 'npm ERR!' errors, like so

```html
C:\Users\Aristophanes>npm install babel-preset-env --save-dev

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Aristophanes\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-30T01_07_46_915Z-debug.log
```

I'm having trouble finding any fix to this. I've tried various methods of installing and updating babel. Any help would be much appreciated.

Latest errors after re-installing npm:

```html
C:\Users\Aristophanes>npm install
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js


> keccak@1.4.0 install C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\keccak
> npm run rebuild || echo "Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."


> keccak@1.4.0 rebuild C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\keccak
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\keccak>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Aristophanes\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\keccak
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! keccak@1.4.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the keccak@1.4.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-30T01_48_19_956Z-debug.log
"Keccak bindings compilation fail. Pure JS implementation will be used."

> scrypt@6.0.3 install C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Aristophanes\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Aristophanes\node_modules\scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@1.9.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.8.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 4.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.4.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aristophanes\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-30T01_48_24_547Z-debug.log
```

Update: after trying various methods, the multiple 'gyp ERR!' and 'npm ERR!' errors are now gone, but now when I try to install packages I get numerous warnings. I've tried installing all of the updates suggested but the warnings remain:

```html
npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read babeljs.io/env to update!
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of babel-eslint@^7.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@2.1.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.1.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-loader@1.9.0 requires a peer of eslint@>=1.6.0 <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.8.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 4.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@5.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^2.10.2 || ^3 || ^4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.4.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-standard-jsx@5.0.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@>=7.6.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: What version of Node and NPM do you have installed?

Comment: Node v8.12.0 and NPM v6.4.1

Comment: Remove `babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1` from package.json, install the new preset-env, delete `node_modules` directory then run `npm install`.

Comment: Well that was like opening a can of worms.

Comment: What are the errors now?

Comment: I've added them to the end of the question now, thanks

Comment: That error is what you get by running that snippet in Python 3 instead of Python 2, so at least a temporary fix would be ensuring that your global `python` is Python 2. That said, I have no idea which package is actually causing the issue here by running the python in the first place.

Comment: The errors are now gone, but various warnings remain and I'm unable to make the necessary updates. The new warnings have been added to question, thanks.

Comment: None of those warnings appear to be related to `babel-preset-env`'s installation so you should be all set.

Comment: install as `npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env`